# Simple php code to count visitors on one page and display in footer

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new, and learning.  I only have a single digital product.  I want to display the total number of purchases made, in my footer (on all pages).  I have not been able to find a lightweight plugin that can do this, nor any code that works.  I am using Woocommerce and since I only have a single product, buyers are taken directly to the checkout page once they click on "Buy".  Once their payment goes through they are taken to a Thankyou page.  I thought that if I can count the number of visitors who visit this Thankyou page and display that, it would give a pretty accurate number of purchases.  I am able to do everything except that I do not know how to count the visitors on just that single page.  My page is id=376, but how could I call that?  Here is the php code that I'm trying.  I think I need to swap the fgets($file, 1000) with the actual page id???

````
$path = 'C:/xampp/apps/wordpress/htdocs/counter.txt';

// Opens counter.txt to read the number of hits.
$file  = fopen( $path, 'r' );
$count = fgets( $file, 1000 );

/*$count = fgets( $file, 1000 );*/
fclose( $file );

// Update the count.
if ($page_id == 376) {
$count = abs( intval( $count ) ) + 1;
}
// Output the updated count.
echo "This product has been purchased <strong>0000{$count}</strong> times\n";

// Opens counter.txt to change new hit number.
$file = fopen( $path, 'w' );
fwrite( $file, $count );
fclose( $file );```
````

Comment: Why don't you just count orders from Woocommerce? You can even use a plugin like this:
https://www.skyverge.com/product/woocommerce-display-order-count/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wc_orders_count( $status )` will retrieve a count of all orders for a status.

You can use a Woocommerce hook to display the code like this on the product page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'se_67926603_count' );

function se_67926603_count() {
    if (is_page(376)) {
        $status = 'completed';
        $count = wc_orders_count( $status );
        echo "This product has been purchased <strong>{$count}</strong> times";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works brilliantly.  Instead of adding it after the cart button, I created a shortcode and added it in footer